# How can I access multiple XAMPP/Apache virtual hosts from another computer on the network without modifying their "hosts" file?

Tags: php, apache, networking, xampp, virtualhost

Currently, what I have is 3 functional virtual hosts in my vhosts.conf file. They are of the following form:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/AFNet"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/AFNet">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but the following 2 have the VirtualHost set to 81 and 82, like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
<VirtualHost *:82>
```

My "hosts" file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       processbooks
127.0.0.1       cmm
```

And then I set my httpd.conf to "listen" to 80, 81, and 82.

Then, in my index.html file located in my htdocs folder, I have a link to each of the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1:81
http://127.0.0.1:82
```

This works like a charm locally, but on another computer, I can only access the index.html and not the pages it links to. How can I direct this correctly?

Comment: You would have to use a browser extension that can inject/replace the Host header eg `Host: processbooks`

Comment: sounds like an issue with how your structuring the links, not a dns issue

Comment: @smith Would you be able to elaborate? I'm not sure how else to structure the links, I've never built a link straight to an IP address before.